# QUERY data based on Alpha Range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to figure out if I can pull data from a sheet in a Google Sheets Workbook based on an alpha range.

For example. I only want data associated with 'last name' that start 'A' and goes through 'F' to be QUERIED and copied to the A-F Sheet.

I assume I'll use part of the following, but I don't know how to adjust the section `contains 'Day 1'` so it only selects an alpha range.

```
=QUERY(responses!A1:I, "Select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where B contains 'Day 1' ")
```

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11qMF2PnJ2jshMhC4G2YS58B6lgL4j9eFTZ5liE4_j4g/edit#gid=0)

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [where clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en#where) supports several types of string matching.

### Method 1: String comparison with >= and <

The query string

```
select A where A < 'G'
```

selects all strings that would precede G in a dictionary, i.e., all that begin with letters A-F. This is case-sensitive. The case-insensitive form is

```
select A where lower(A) < 'g'
```

#### More complex examples

```
select A where lower(A)<'cp'
```

selects in the range a-co.

```
select A where lower(A) >= 'cp' and lower(A) < 'hb'
```

selects the range cp-ha.

### Method 2: regular expressions

The query string

```
where B matches '^[A-F].*'
```

selects the rows where the content of B begins with a letter from A to F. (The regular expression means: ^ beginning of line, [A-F] one character in this range, .* other characters may follow.)

The match is case-sensitive. Its case-insensitive version would be

```
where lower(B) matches '^[a-f].*'
```

#### More complex examples

Matching strings in alphabetic range "a" to "co".

```
where lower(B) matches '^([ab]|c[a-o]).*'
```

Here | separates alternatives. Beginning with a or b is okay. So is beginning with c, but only if followed by a letter in range a-o.

Matching the range cp-ha:

```
where lower(B) matches '^(c[p-z]|[d-g]|ha).*'
```

There are three alternatives here: c followed by p-z, anything beginning with d-g , and ha.

Comment: Awesome, THANK YOU! What if I needed to QUERY by `a-fm` instead of `a-f`, is that possible?

Comment: What if I want the following tabs. Tab A = `a-co` and Tab B = `cp-ha`? Last name = Coleman would be on Tab A.  Last name = Crawford would be on Tab B. Is that possible?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Actually, I overcomplicated things: see the simpler "Method 1".

Comment: One more question regarding this. Is it possible to achieve this 'while' alphabetizing the rows based on column "B"? Thanks again and have a great weekend!

Comment: Yes, add `order by B` at the end. Please see [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses) which explains the use of all language clauses.

Comment: How can the "More complex examples" be adjusted to allow for an alpha range to the 4th character? For example: Only in the range of `Mimz to Sand` Thanks!